# How to decode a reserved escape character in a request URI on a web server?

Tags: parsing, url, escaping, uri, percent-encoding

It is pretty clear that a web server has to decode any escaped unreserved character (such as alphanums, etc.) to do the URI comparison. For example, `http://www.example.com/~user/index.htm` shall be identical to `http://www.example.com/%7Euser/index.htm`.

My question is, what are we gonna do with the escaped reserved characters?

An example would be `%2F`, or `/`. If there is an `%2F` in the request URI, should the parser of web server replace it with a `/`? In the above example, it would mean that `http://www.example.com/~user%2Findex.htm` would be the same as `http://www.example.com/~user/index.htm`? Although I tried it on an Apache server (2.2.17 Unix) and it looks like it gives a "404 Not Found" error.

So does that mean `%2F` and other escaped reserved characters shall be left alone (at least before the URI comparison)?

#### Background information:

There are two places in RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1) mentioning the escape decoding issue:

> The Request-URI is transmitted in the format specified in section 3.2.1. If the Request-URI is encoded using the “% HEX HEX” encoding [42], the origin server MUST decode the Request-URI in order to properly interpret the request. Servers SHOULD respond to invalid Request-URIs with an appropriate status code.

and

> Characters other than those in the “reserved” and “unsafe” sets (see RFC 2396 [42]) are equivalent to their “"%" HEX HEX” encoding.

(according to http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/2 "unsafe" is a mistake and shall be removed from the spec. So we are only looking at "reserved" here.)

FYI, the definition of such characters in RFC 2396:

> reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
>
> unreserved  = alphanum | mark
>
> mark        = "-" | "_" | "." | "!" | "˜" | "*" | "’" | "(" | ")"

Comment: I think the post answer itself. Good job :-) "Characters **other than** those in the “reserved” and “unsafe” sets (see RFC 2396 [42]) are equivalent to their “"%" HEX HEX” encoding." I suspect the fragment portion of the URI is more liberal.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:**

Decode percent-encoded unreserved characters,
keep percent-encoded reserved characters.

---

The URI standard is [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66), which currently is [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

[Section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6) is about *Normalization and Comparison*, where [section 6.2.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.2) explains what to do with percent-encoded octets:

> These URIs should be normalized by decoding any percent-encoded octet that corresponds to an unreserved character […]

As explicitly stated in [section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) (bold emphasis mine):

- [Unreserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3):

  > URIs that differ in the replacement of an unreserved character with its corresponding percent-encoded US-ASCII octet **are** equivalent
- [Reserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2):

  > URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its corresponding percent-encoded octet are **not** equivalent.